# How to compress a directory that it names starts with -

Tags: command-line, zip

I need to compress this directory:
`-YDHEmmD9DDD=` but this is the output:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option 'Y' not supported)
```

Comment: Express the filename as `./-YDHEmmD9DD\=`.

Comment: or in general, terminate the command line options with `--` to tell the command that the next argument is not an option, but a file name that really starts with a `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--` to indicate the end of options ex.:

```
$ zip -r my.zip -YDHEmmD9DDD=

zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option 'Y' not supported)
```

but

```
$ zip -r my.zip -- -YDHEmmD9DDD=
updating: -YDHEmmD9DDD=/ (stored 0%)
  adding: -YDHEmmD9DDD=/somefile (stored 0%)
  adding: -YDHEmmD9DDD=/other file (stored 0%)
```